# How to calculate the centered approximation of ${\frac{{df}}{{dt}} = - \frac{f}{\tau }}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, truncation-error

In the textbook of An Introduction to Computational Methods in Hydrodynamics by Willy Benz. 2.2 Differential Equations.

[image]

I know how to derive the general formula above
$$
f\left( {{x_0} + \Delta x} \right) = f\left( {{x_0}} \right) + {\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_{{x_0}}}\Delta x + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right)_{{x_0}}}\Delta {x^2} + O\left( {\Delta {x^3}} \right)
$$
$$
f_{k + 1}^n = f_k^n + {\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_k}\Delta x_{k + \frac{1}{2}}^n + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right)_k}{\left( {\Delta x_{k + \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right)^2} + O\left( {\Delta {x^3}} \right)
$$

--
$$
f\left( {{x_0} - \Delta x} \right) = f\left( {{x_0}} \right) + {\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_{{x_0}}}\left( { - \Delta x} \right) + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right)_{{x_0}}}{\left( { - \Delta x} \right)^2} + O\left( {{{\left( { - \Delta x} \right)}^3}} \right)
$$
$$
f_{k - 1}^n = f_k^n + {\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_k}\Delta x_{k - \frac{1}{2}}^n + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right)_k}{\left( {\Delta x_{k - \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right)^2} + O\left( {{{\left( {\Delta x} \right)}^3}} \right)
$$

--
$$
f_{k + 1}^n - f_{k - 1}^n = {\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_k}\left( {\Delta x_{k + \frac{1}{2}}^n - \Delta x_{k - \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right) + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right)_k}\left( {{{\left( {\Delta x_{k + \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right)}^2} - {{\left( {\Delta x_{k - \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right)}^2}} \right) + O\left( {\Delta {x^3}} \right){\text{ }}
$$
$$
{\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}} \right)_k} = \frac{{f_{k + 1}^n - f_{k - 1}^n}}{{2 \cdot \Delta {x_k}}} - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}}} \right)_k}\frac{{\left( {{{\left( {\Delta x_{k + \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right)}^2} - {{\left( {\Delta x_{k - \frac{1}{2}}^n} \right)}^2}} \right)}}{{2 \cdot \Delta {x_k}}} + O\left( {\Delta {x^2}} \right)
$$

---

But I am stuck below:

given ${\frac{{df}}{{dt}} =  - \frac{f}{\tau }}$ & $f(0)=1$

I know how to get these 2,

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\left[ {{\text{forward difference approximation}}} \right]\\
\frac{{\delta f}}{{\delta t}} \equiv \frac{{{f^{n + 1}} - {f^n}}}{{\Delta t}}\\
- \frac{1}{\tau } \cdot f\left( {{t_0}} \right) \approx \frac{{f\left( {{t_0} + \Delta t} \right) - f\left( {{t_0}} \right)}}{{\Delta t}}
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\left[ {{\text{backward difference approximation}}} \right]\\
\frac{{\delta f}}{{\delta t}} \equiv \frac{{{f^n} - {f^{n - 1}}}}{{\Delta t}}\\
- \frac{1}{\tau } \cdot f\left( {{t_0}} \right) \approx \frac{{f\left( {{t_0}} \right) - f\left( {{t_0} - \Delta t} \right)}}{{\Delta t}}
\end{array}
$$

**but how can you get the centered approximation of the given function as following?**

**and how can you get numerical solutions of it?**

$$
\frac{{{f^{n + 1}} - {f^n}}}{{\Delta t}} =  - \frac{1}{{2\tau }}\left( {{f^{n + 1}} + {f^n}} \right) 
$$
$$ 
\frac{{f\left( {{t_0} + \Delta t} \right) - f\left( {{t_0}} \right)}}{{\Delta t}} =  - \frac{1}{{2\tau }} \cdot \left( {f\left( {{t_0} + \Delta t} \right) + f\left( {{t_0}} \right)} \right) 
$$
[image]

Following is the graph for a better visualization of the solutions at different time points.
[image]

---

Update 20210201_174816

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{{f^{n + 1}} - {f^n}}}{{\Delta t}} =  - \frac{1}{\tau } \cdot \frac{{{f^{n + 1}} + {f^n}}}{2}\\
\frac{{{f^{n + 1}} - {f^n}}}{{\Delta t}} =  - \frac{1}{{2\tau }}\left( {{f^{n + 1}} + {f^n}} \right)\\
{f^{n + 1}} - {f^n} =  - \frac{{\Delta t}}{{2\tau }}\left( {{f^{n + 1}} + {f^n}} \right)\\
set:\left\{ {\alpha  = \Delta t/\tau } \right.\\
{f^{n + 1}} - {f^n} =  - \frac{\alpha }{2}\left( {{f^{n + 1}} + {f^n}} \right)\\
\left( {1 + \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right){f^{n + 1}} = {f^n} \cdot \left( {1 - \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)\\
{f^{n + 1}} = \frac{{\left( {1 - \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)}}{{\left( {1 + \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)}}{f^n}\\
given:\left\{ {\alpha  = \Delta t/\tau  = 0.2} \right.\\
{f^{n + 1}} = \frac{{\left( {1 - \frac{{0.2}}{2}} \right)}}{{\left( {1 + \frac{{0.2}}{2}} \right)}}{f^n}\\
{f^n} = {\left( {\frac{{\left( {1 - \frac{{0.2}}{2}} \right)}}{{\left( {1 + \frac{{0.2}}{2}} \right)}}} \right)^n} \cdot f\left( 0 \right) = {\left( {\frac{{\left( {2 - 0.2} \right)}}{{\left( {2 + 0.2} \right)}}} \right)^n} \cdot 1\\
{f^{2\tau /0.2\tau }} = {\left( {\frac{{\left( {2 - 0.2} \right)}}{{\left( {2 + 0.2} \right)}}} \right)^{10}} = 0.134430632749
\end{array}
$$

Above does not match with the textbook, which is 0.1407.

Answer (score 1):

The comment right below Eq. (2.2.4) is giving you a clue

> Notice that (2.2.4) has been centered in a somewhat surprising way. Using a straightforward analog of (2.1.9) for estimating the time derivative of $f$ would lead to an intrinsically unstable and therefore useless numerical scheme.

Apparently that is further discussed in section 3, but I can give you an argument here.

> **How NOT to do it**

If you stick to Eq. (2.1.9) you end up with

$$
\frac{f^{(n+1)} - f^{(n-1)}}{2\Delta t} = -\frac{f(\text{where should I evaluate this?})}{\tau} \tag{1}
$$

the problem is that if you decide evaluate the right hand side (RHS) at $t^{(n)}$ then you will two initial conditions to solve the iteration. A better approach is to evaluate in the average of the points of the grid

$$
\frac{f^{(n+1)} - f^{(n-1)}}{2\Delta t} = -\frac{f^{(n+1)} + f^{(n-1)}}{2\tau} \tag{2}
$$

which can be expressed as

$$
f^{(n+1)} = \frac{1 - \alpha}{1 + \alpha} f^{(n-1)} ~~~\alpha= \frac{\Delta t}{\tau} \tag{3}
$$

and the issue with this one is that you end up with parallel tracks for even/odd indices.

> **HOW TO DO IT**

Use forward difference on the derivative, and evaluate the RHS on the average of the grid

$$
\underbrace{\frac{f^{(n+1)} - f^{(n)}}{\Delta t}}_{\text{forward}} = -\frac{1}{\tau}\underbrace{\frac{f^{(n+1)} + f^{(n)}}{2}}_{\text{average point}} \tag{4}
$$

Rearranging a bit

$$
f^{(n+1)} = \frac{2 - \alpha}{2 + \alpha} f^{(n)} \tag{5}
$$

whose solution is

$$
f^{(n)} = \left(\frac{2 - \alpha}{2 + \alpha}  \right)^n f^{(0)} \tag{6}
$$

> EDIT 20210203

These are the solutions for all the methods

\begin{eqnarray}
f_{\rm forward}^{(n)} &=& (1 - \alpha)^n f^{(0)} \\
f_{\rm backward}^{(n)} &=& \left(\frac{1}{1 + \alpha}\right)^n f^{(0)} \\
f_{\rm centered}^{(n)} &=& \left(\frac{2 - \alpha}{2 + \alpha}\right)^n f^{(0)}
\end{eqnarray}

and in graphical form

[image]

You can see that lines are in a different order in the picture you posted ... I'm leaning towards a problem with the book

Comment: Why you can "Use forward difference on the derivative, and evaluate the RHS on the average of the grid"? How can you convert from (2) to (4), is it still centered approximation?

Comment: Also the equation should be ${f^{n + 1}} = \frac{{\left( {1 - \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)}}{{\left( {1 + \frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)}}{f^n}$. And with this equation, I did calculated the result which is ${f^{2\tau /0.2\tau }} = {\left( {\frac{{\left( {2 - 0.2} \right)}}{{\left( {2 + 0.2} \right)}}} \right)^{10}} = 0.134430632749$ does not match the textbook. 
I will put this in the update of my question.

Comment: @Nor.Z Thanks for catching the missing `2` factor, just fixed it. As for the discrepancy, not sure what's happening, will dig into it a bit later today

Comment: If you are interested in the original file https://file.io/gDG0VcEWlK0w (only can download once)

Comment: Note that, the plot in the textbook might be mistaken, ie: the labels of the lines for forward and backward is misplaced I think.

Comment: @Nor.Z Updated my answer

Comment: For (1) & (3), I do know there are lots of problems. But why are you allowed to "Use forward difference on the derivative, and evaluate the RHS on the average of the grid" in equation (4)? I can't find a strict explanation from (3) to (4).